# Defaults in CanJS controller constructor

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-control

I have a controller that is similar to:

```
var TheController = can.Control.extend({
    defaults: {
    field: undefined
},

"pluginName": "theControllerPlugin",
},
{
"init" : function(element, options) {
    field = options["fieldInOptions"];
```

Right now this field is acting essentially as a static variable. I would prefer it acted as an instance variable. Is this possible and what is the syntax in canJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is `this.options.field`, any default property can be accessed with `this.options.defaultProperty`.